# C# extern int? How do I make a global var across classes and namespaces?

Tags: c#-4.0, extern

As an old C/C++ programmer, I want to keep a global `int` counter across
all of MY namespaces and classes.

```
public static extern int EventCount;
```

Is not working; the VS2010 compiler won't let me have an `extern int`. 
Even with a `DLLImport`.

```
[DllImport ( "SilverlightApplication37.dll" )]
public static extern int EventCount;
```

VS2010 complains,

```
Error   1   The modifier 'extern' is not valid for this item
```

So how do I have a global `int` across all my code?

Cheers!

dr.K

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing. For holding data, C# has fields, properties and local variables. You can make a static class and then create a property, like this:

```
public static class GlobalData
{    
    public static int EventCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @dr Well, C# is about objects. In order to write C# you have to think C#. I've seen a lot of C# code written by C/C++ developers, and it looks really bad because they didn't know how to take advantage of the great things C# gives you, and tried to force their vision of the world on programming in C#. Before you write code in C#, learn from examples. Learn from people who think C# and then your life will be easier and much more fun.

Comment: trying... i'm going to tinker with it. but what I want to do is not at all obtuse or odd.

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do is to create a new static class with static fields to store global variables. It's always called "GlobalValues" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a solution to directly access a global variable in a C dll via C#. But, if you have access to the dll source code you can add an accessor function for the global.

So if in your C library you have:

```
__declspec(dllexport) extern int EventCount;
```

You will need to add:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl getEventCount(void);

int __decl getEventCount(void) {
    return EventCount;
}
```

Then in your C# code somewhere you will need something like:

```
[DllImport("SilverlightApplication37.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int32 getEventCount();
```

Answer (score -1):

`public static int EventCount;` should do the trick.

Comment: testing... i don't think so but I don't know so.